# I am at a loss of how to create an appropriate flow using webflux

Tags: spring-webflux

Problem statement: I have a POST request to a **booking-service** API that gets a BookingRecord. I map it to extract the values so as to call another **fare-service** API using WebClient. I receive a `Mono<Fare>` from that call. I need to check whether the value of getFare() method of BookingRecord type is same as the getFare() of the Fare type returned by the WebClient. If not, I need to raise and exception, and pass it on to the caller. Here caller is another Microservice, **ui-service** calling the booking-service API (so how should I deal with this, pass the error back or else what is the best thing to do?) or else I will save the new BookingRecord and return the id of that record to the caller. What is the best flow sequence for this? I tried my best without much success and am pasting the code here.

```
public HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> book = request ->
    {
request.bodyToMono(BookingRecord.class)
        .map(br ->
        {
            this.webClient.get()
                    .uri("/fares/get/{flightNumber}/{flightDate}",
                         br.getFlightNumber(),
                         br.getFlightDate())
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Fare.class)
                    .map(f ->
                    {
                        if (!f.getFare()
                                .equals(br.getFare()))
                        {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Fare is tampered");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            id = bookingRepository.save(br).getId();
                        }
                        return id;
                    })
                    .subscribe();
            return id;
        });

return ServerResponse.ok()
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(id));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tweaking, this is what I did. Hope its the right thing to do. 1. I raise a 500 Http error from the fare-service itself instead of checking in the booking-service.

```
public HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> getFare = request ->
    {
        String flightNumber = request.pathVariable("flightNumber");
        String flightDate   = request.pathVariable("flightDate");
        String fare         = request.pathVariable("fare");

        Mono<ServerResponse> notFound = ServerResponse.notFound()
                .build();

        return Mono
                .justOrEmpty(faresRepository.getFareByFlightNumberAndFlightDateAndFare(flightNumber,
                                                                                       flightDate,
                                                                                       fare))
                .flatMap(f -> ServerResponse.ok()
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .body(fromObject(f)))
                .switchIfEmpty(notFound);
    };
```

2. Handled the exception like so in booking-service using onStatus() method

   ```
   public HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> book = request ->
   {

       logger.info("Inside Book function");
       return request.bodyToMono(BookingRecord.class)
               .flatMap(br ->
               {
                   logger.info("Calling fare-service");
                   return this.webClient.get()
                           .uri("/fares/get/{flightNumber}/{flightDate}/{fare}",
                                br.getFlightNumber(),
                                br.getFlightDate(),
                                br.getFare())
                           .retrieve()
                           .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError,
                                     x -> Mono
                                             .error(new RuntimeException("Fare has been tampered with!!")))
                           .bodyToMono(Fare.class);

               })
               .map(fare ->
               {
                   logger.info("Saving a BookingRecord");
                   BookingRecord br = new BookingRecord();
                   br.setFlightNumber(fare.getFlightNumber());
                   br.setFlightDate(fare.getFlightDate());
                   br.setFare(fare.getFare());

                   long id = bookingRepository.save(br)
                           .getId();

                   return id;
               })
               .flatMap(id -> ServerResponse.ok()
                       .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(id)));
   };
   ```

This way, I get an exception for fare tampering or get the id for a successful db save.